# VHD Upload Performance Throttling Or Restart Capability Of add-azurevhd

Tags: azure

Is there a way to limit or pause and resume `add-azurevhd`?

I am on a 8 Mbps second upload from my provider which gives me 5 Mps actual and the operation takes *understandably* a day and a half; so being able to pause or resume would be very helpful.

It also not clear to me if the command line attribute for `add-azurevhd` `-NumberOfUploaderThreads` would make any difference in performance either way.

Comment: The only way upload threads would make a difference is if you have a wide enough pipe to send large enough chunks concurrently to make a difference.  Large volume data uploads can be an issue - you may wish to look at the Import/Export service instead (depending on your needs and location): http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way upload threads would make a difference is if you have a wide enough pipe to send large enough chunks concurrently to make a difference. Large volume data uploads can be an issue - you may wish to look at the [Import/Export service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/) instead (depending on your needs and location).